# Mysql count vs select performance in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a very large database (~10 million rows) and I want to list these things as fast as possible in a table. I have few options :

1. **I can limit the rows from Mysql** - Not Preferred as I want to count the rows with specific type of data say attachment
2. **Fetch all rows and use while loop to limit 1000 records each time** - I think it's good to do but calling 10 million rows in memory looks insane and I am quite sure that it must have worse performance.
3. **Count the total data and then list using limit** - but mysql count is a deal breaker as inspite of unique and indexed id I have faced bad time with mysql count.

What is the best way to do this?

If I just want to list 10 million rows and parsing data using php to stop it and display each time 1000 rows it is a bad idea ?

Comment: Depend of what you fetch and how your query looks. No idea how you 10 millions rows will be display, but user can't looks at 10 millions information at once so use pagination system for example (look at Datatable maybe) and fetch  what you need to display. You can do the pagination alone with Ajax : use `limit 0, 1000` if your query for page 1 for example to fetch first 1000 row, `limit 1000, 1000` for page 2, etc.

Comment: @MickaelLeger so i said that we are limiting with while loop and listing only 1000 rows. question is calling 10 million rows will kill server ??

Comment: Depend of the server, the query...but why you want to call 10 miliions rows? The point is not to call ALL and do a while loop to limit 1000 records each time. The point is to call 1000 records then make a new query with other 1000 rows if need, etc. Hard to give you an answer with no idea how your data looks like, how your query looks like and how you display them

Comment: @MickaelLeger i want to count the exact no of images in wordpress post table. wordpress has built in function wp_count but that is same select count and i know count kills server so i was thinking to list all rows (only three column ) do a while loop count all but display only 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres some things to consider:

- Is the database optimized? if yes, skip
- Indexing columns you want to filter the search from
- Select the columns you require from it only (instead of select *)
- If you want to count the total and the id is sequencial, you get select the latest row and count based on the id if it's 'that slow'
- If you're looking at some sort of pagination, you can count the rows and select only a few records based of an user input (select with limit 1000, skip '1000' when its page 2, etc)

You wouldn't want 10million data in your "memory" when you'd be using 0.1% of it right?

Comment: And who would bother looking through 10 million row even if you show them in groups of 100

Comment: @RiggsFolly its live project and people are looking for these data. question is if i call select 10 million it will kill server or if its indexed and optimized it will go smooth ?

Comment: That depends on your server specs. Indexing the most searchable fields and having a decent database structure makes things smoother but it depends from the query, to the structure to the envoironment

Comment: @abr columns are indexed. if all data are of same type mysql max will give me last row count but unfortunately that is not the case. its mixed table and all sort of data are there

Comment: 'mixed table' 'all sort of data'. If you're searching for more concrete ways to optimize, show us the table structure and the query